# [mac Monterey][Python 3.10.4][tkinter 8.6] Calling tkinter askOpenfilename crashes when repeatedly creating a window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a python program that allows users to repeatedly press a key that will create a tkinter window where they can open an image an manipulate it.

The problem is, by the 3rd time, tkinter always crashes.

I can't figure out why..

I have simplified the code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root=None):

        super().__init__(root) 
        self.root = root
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='open')


def run(title):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title(title)
    root.geometry(str(100) + "x" + str(100))
    app = Application(root=root)

    app.mainloop()


def main():
    run("1")
    run("2")
    run("3")
    run("4")
    run("5")
    run("6")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help would be very useful.

The error message is long. But here is a relevant part:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000001c
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000001c
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [10115]
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I got all 6 file dialogs.

Comment: Please add the traceback from the crash.

Comment: I've added some more details on the error message. I feel it might be a mac issue with that particular version

Comment: Also I'm using a MBP 16' with plenty of RAM and HDD

Comment: I'm using a MacBook M1.

Comment: Anything that causes the interpreter to crash like that is a Python bug, not a problem with your code. You should report it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fix for this as of right now. The Tk maintainers acknowledged the bug and are working on it.

Ref link is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/92603)